# How to get grid cell value given column name in jquery for kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid

Is there a equivalent for below code in kendo grid:

```
var gridCell = $('.grid-row-selected td.grid-cell[data-name= ' + columnName + ']');
```

Above code is for the mvc grid, where it automatically gives HTML tag on grid-row-selected on selecting a cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cell value from the model of a grid.

**Option 1:**

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem("tbody tr[data-uid='0656dd82-93c5-4159-b4f1-ab62cddce133']").columnName;
```

Here `data-uid` is the Unique Id of the row of the column which you want to get.

**Option 2:**
If you are using editable Kendo grid, `k-grid-edit-row` class get's added to the selected row. So, you can get the selected row column value like below:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem("tbody tr.k-grid-edit-row").columnName;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for an answer then you can try using following steps:

- First get specific row from which you want to get value of specific
  column by name. In my requirement found row using row's UID with
  specific column class name.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var row = grid.dataSource.getByUid("your-row-uid");
```

- And at last get your selected row specific cell value by it's class
  name.

`$(row).find("td.column_className").text();`