# How do I access a row object of this grid?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, grid

I am trying to access an individual row from a grid in Kendo UI so that I can run operations on the selected entries in the row. However, my code is not correctly grabbing the row itself and I do not know how to resolve this.

I've tried binding the grid to an event that, when changed, will fire my method in order to grab whichever row was toggled.

```
const row = arg.sender.element.closest("tr")
const grid = $("#ECUs").getKendoGrid()
const dataItem = grid.dataItem(row)
```

Results:

```
I.fn.init [prevObject: I.fn.init(1)]
length: 0
prevObject: I.fn.init [div#ECUs.k-grid.k-widget.k-display-block]
__proto__: w
```

(Sorry, I apparently don't have enough reputation to post images)

Ideally, I would expect to get a `tr` object back in the first method, but I'm getting absolutely nothing instead. Does anybody know how to correct this to access the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a click event on one of the columns, you can access the table row using some jquery.

```
function onClickListener(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
You can use the **edit** event of a grid to get the currently selected row model.

```
edit: function(e) { console.log(e.model); }
```

Here, `e.model` contains the row data and you can access the particular column value by `e.model.columnName`.

**Option 2:** You can get the row model data like below from the other functions.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478061/8733214